# Convert java keystore (.jks format) file to public format (.pem / .cer) file type

Tags: java, keystore, jks

Require command to convert .jks file type to .cer/.pem file type

Answer (score 0):

At file location, need to give following command in cmd prompt window:

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore {file-location}\filename.jks -alias filename -file {file-location}\filename.cer
```

And the new formatter file will be generated at the specified (same) location

Answer (score 0):

**Extract .jks file into a text file :**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {key_file}.jks > {opened_key}.txt
```

**Pull .cer file out of .jks file:**

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore {key_file}.jks -alias {alias_name_to_extract} -file {alias_name}.cer
```

**List certificate in .kdb file.**

```
runmqckm -cert -list -db {key_file}.kdb
```